# Gene Protein Sequence Database

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, ncbi

I am wondering if there is a way to download or retrieve all the protein sequences of Genes from NCBI. I have the lots of GeneIDs I would like to iterate and retrieve their protein sequence.

Is there a package I use for this or link to the protein sequence of Genes from NCBI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can download data directly from the NCBI website. Searching for 'protein sequences of genes' it returns 45260 records, which can be downloaded by clicking `send to` (right-top corner) and saving as a file.
Check [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=protein%20sequences%20of%20genes). After downloading, you can simply load data from a file.

If you were asking about programmatically downloading data, you can use [this FTP](https://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/gene/DATA/), download latest data, unpack and find what you were looking for, filtering by GeneID. Most of these files are updated daily. You can read more [here](https://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/gene/README) and based on this choose which file contains the data you need. As far as I'm concerned, you would need either *gene2accession.gz* or *gene2refseq.gz*